# lighttpd on Fedora permission issues

Tags: permissions, fedora, lighttpd

I'm trying to get started with lighttpd on Fedora 16 to run a RESTful api for development. Right now even with the most basic sample config file I'm getting 404 pages when I know the pages I'm pointing at exist. From reading other questions I'm leaning towards this being a permissions issue, but I'm confused about how lighttpd runs on Fedora.

There's a user called "lighttpd" not "www-data"? I can't see this user in the system-config-users tool and I can't su into it to check which permissions it has.

I'm trying to point lighttpd to "/var/www/lighttpd" which has some example pages in it. The permissions for the files inside are set to -rw-r--r-- and the permissions for the folder containing them are drwxr-xr-x. Doesn't that mean that any user can view these files?

I'm not sure what else I should be checking as I don't have much experience with server configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I was following the tutorial configuration [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/TutorialConfiguration) so the lighttpd.conf file contains

```
server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/" 

server.port = 3000

mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html", 
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png" 
)
```

and I was just trying to get the basic example page working.

Comment: can you post your lighthttpd.conf file ?

Comment: If this looks like a permissions problem and the file permissions are set correctly, my gut instinct tells me it could be SELinux. Try disabling it to see if that fixes anything. You might need to change the security context of your webroot folder if SELinux turns out to be the culprit.

Comment: @KennyRasschaert I just installed an Ubuntu virtual machine and am having similar issues so I'll look into this possibility. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, while Fedora has SELinux installed and enabled by default, Ubuntu does not.

Comment: @KennyRasschaert On ubuntu I just didn't notice lighttpd had started itself when I installed it so I was trying to start it again without stopping it. It's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd doesn't serve directories by default. either enable dirlistings:

```
dir-listing.activate = "enable"
```

or activate index files (and create one!)

```
index-file.names = ( "index.html" )
```

(or both. if an index file exists it has priority over dirlistings)